# Compare with previous props in getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

Think of a component that has a prop 'name' and state 'elapse'.

```
new Component(name) => "Hi {name}. It's been {elapse} seconds"
```

`{elapse}` should be reset to 0 when the prop `{name}` changes.

If the prop changes from 'Alice' to 'Bob' at 10 seconds,
the message should change from

> Hi Alice. It's been 10 seconds

to

> Hi Bob. It's been 0 seconds

- `getDerivedStateFromProps` cannot be used because `{elapse}` is not a pure function of `{name}`, and I cannot return 0 because it may be called on re-render.
- `componentDidUpdate` will eventually update `{elapse}` to 0, but before that, the invalid state *"Hi Bob. It's been 0 seconds"* is shown to the user.

Can `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `componentDidUpdate` implement this scenario?

1. In many cases the state is not a pure function of props. Is `getDerivedStateFromProps` only for stateless functional components? Does react encourage the use of stateless components?
2. How can `getDerivedStateFromProps` replace `componentWillReceiveProps` in stateful components?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look around you'll see you're not the first one having this problem - it was thoroughly discussed on github <sup>[1](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/721) [2](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12188) [3](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/6#discussion_r162865372)</sup> and in a thread on hackernews [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16694785). The recommended solution is to mirror the props you need to check in the state:

```js
state = { name: "", lastTime: Date.now() }

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.name !== prevState.name) {
        return { name: nextProps.name, lastTime: Date.now() };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated. I thought getDerivedStateFromProps has no access to 'this' keyword.

Comment: @mq7 Answer fixed. This should solve your problem now. Let me know if you have any further issues with it :)

Comment: I am not sure mirroring is a good way, but I cannot find any other solution.

Comment: For some cases mirroring may be required, but for this situation (and probably the situation of many others who find this answer on google) I think the more recommended react way is to use an uncontrolled component with a key, as I've explained in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195052/1347649

Answer (score 2):

set initial state keep in mind the prop we pass down is `{ name:'alice' }`. But in order for `getDerivedStateFromProps` to be able to see if name changed we must mirror it in our state and acess it with `prevState.name`. We cannot use `this` inside the lifecycle method because it is `getDerivedStateFromProps` is `pure`.

```
state = {time: 0, endtime: 0, name:'' }
```

When component mounts set the clock to begin incrementing by 1 every second.

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.setClock();
}
```

When component unmounts `clearInterval`

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.clockCall)
}
```

`setInterval` will call `incrementClock` every second increasing the timer by 1 every 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

```
setClock = () => {
  this.setState({time: 0})
  this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
    this.incrementClock();
  }, 1000)

}
```

This is where we set the state of time and increment it every second.

```
incrementClock = () => {
  this.setState((prevstate) => {time: prevstate.time + 1 })
}
```

If the name changes, we save the time in a new state piece called `endtime` and that is what we use to display `hey alice its been ${this.state.endtime} seconds` we also reset the timer to 0.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.name !== nextProps.name)
    return { time: 0, endtime:prevState.time };
    return null;
}
```

Here are the two examples of how you would use `getDerivedStateFromProps` compared to `componentWillRecieveProps`

Before

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    derivedData: computeDerivedState(this.props)
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.someValue !== nextProps.someValue) {
      this.setState({
        derivedData: computeDerivedState(nextProps)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

After

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  // Initialize state in constructor,
  // Or with a property initializer.
  state = {};

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.someMirroredValue !== nextProps.someValue) {
      return {
        derivedData: computeDerivedState(nextProps),
        someMirroredValue: nextProps.someValue
      };
    }

    // Return null to indicate no change to state.
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does getDerivedStateFromProps have access to 'this'? It's a static method.

Comment: yeah mixed it up that shouldve been nextProps.name just a typo, the state of name comes from props.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already an accepted answer here and for some cases the mirroring of the props to the state may be required, but in your situation, I think that you actually want to make your component an 'uncontrolled component with a key' as explained here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Then you would use it like this:

```
<Component key={name} name={name}/>
```

And every time the name updated it would render a new instance of the Component, so would restart the counter.

Answer (score -4):

As of version 16.3, the recommended way to update state in response to props changes is with the new static getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle. (That lifecycle is called when a component is created and each time it receives new props):
See this: [link]https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. My question is exactly about the new lifecycle.

Comment: [Link-only answers are not considered good answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I meant that I am already aware of the new lifecycle, and I posted this question because I don't know the right way to apply the new statid method in some scenarios.