# Where to move setState() callback from deprecated componentWillReceiveProps()?

Tags: reactjs

React 16 deprecates `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle method. The preferred replacement is new `getDerivedStateFromProps()` or `componentDidUpdate()`. Now let's suppose I have some code like that:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if (this.props.foo !== newProps.foo) {
    this.setState({foo: newProps.foo}, () => this.handleNewFoo()});
  }
}
```

I could try moving the code to `getDerivedStateFromProps()` like that:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.foo !== newProps.foo) {
    return {foo: newProps.foo};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

but what do I do with the callback from `setState()`? Is moving it to `componentDidUpdate` the only option? I'd rather have `this.handleNewFoo()` invoked before `render()` to avoid visual and performance cost of two renders.

Comment: `this.handleNewFoo()` would be called after the render anyway. Calling `setState()` always triggers a new (re)render.

Comment: @Chris is right. The callback of `setState` is called after a re-render anyways so this would not be different to your current implementation in terms of performance and re-renders. If you want to prevent unnecessary re-renders you would have to calculate the final state in advance.

Comment: What is handleNewFoo? Please, provide all relevant code.

Comment: @Chris ah right, I've missed that. Please post it as an answer so I could accept. By the way, why did you remove `react-16` tag?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you haven't read this blog post you should 
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state

1. If you are simply assigning props.foo to state.foo without any calculation / processing then you need to ask yourself should you really need that field in state.  Because you can always use this.props.foo instead of this.state.foo.
2. what is this.handleNewFoo method does?
   are you doing another setState inside handleNewFoo?  if you are then you are triggering multiple render calls.

eg.

```
this.setState({foo: this.props.foo} // one render call, () => this.handleNewFoo())

const handleNewFoo = () => {
  this.setState({ }) // another render call
}
```

If you are not doing any setState inside handleNewFoo then ask yourself does handleNewFoo has to be called on prop change?

If you are using setState inside the handleFoo i would suggest something like this

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.foo !== newProps.foo) {
    return this.handleNewFoo(this.props.foo, prevState);
  } else {
    return prevState;
  }
}

handleNewFoo(foo, state) {
  // do some calculation using foo
  const derivedFoo = state.foo + foo;

  // if your are using immutability_helper library.
  const derivedState = update(state, { foo: {$set:  derivedFoo}});

  return derivedState
}
```

It all depends on what you are doing inside this.handleNewFoo

**EDIT:**

Above code won't work as @Darko mentioned `getDerivedStateFromProps` is static method and you cannot access `this` inside it. And you cannot get the previous props inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723019/compare-with-previous-props-in-getderivedstatefromprops).  So this answer is completely wrong.

one solution is to use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState(...)
}, [props.foo])
```

this `useEffect` will call whenever the `props.foo` is changed.  And also the component will be rendered twice one for prop change and another for `setState` inside `useEffect`.  Just be careful with `setState` inside `useEffect` as it can cause infinite loop.

Comment: This won't work as `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a static method and you cannot access `this` inside it.