# How to call non-static methods and props methods in a static method in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

NOTE: There is an edit at the bottom.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I didn't quite understand the solutions so I thought I should ask a new one. So here's my situation.

I have a class component that had the deprecated method `componentWillReceiveProps` (I didn't create it originally) so I was tasked with changing it with an not deprecated one so I used the static `getDerivedStateFromProps` as others like `componentDidUpdate` don't work as intended.

This `getDerivedStateFromProps` needs to access 2 functions from the Redux state (they've been mapped to props via `mapStateToProps`) and a non-static method. I've tried calling the non-static one as `ClassName.method` and it doesn't work. I've tried calling the ones mapped to props via `props.method` and `Classname.props.method` and neither works.

Here's my code (it's the original `willReceiveProps` - note that `loadInvoicesFromFile` is inside this very class):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.invoicesCollection !== nextProps.invoicesCollection) {
        this.props.clearData();
        this.loadInvoicesFromFile(nextProps.invoicesCollection, nextProps.debtors);
        setTimeout(x => {
            if(nextProps.invoicesCollection && nextProps.invoicesCollection.length > 0)
                this.props.validateInvoices();
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

What I am currently trying:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, props) {
    if (props.invoicesCollection !== nextProps.invoicesCollection) {
        props.clearData();
        loadInvoicesFromFile(nextProps.invoicesCollection, nextProps.debtors);
        setTimeout(x => {
            if(nextProps.invoicesCollection && nextProps.invoicesCollection.length > 0)
            props.validateInvoices();
        }, 500);
    }
    return null;
}
```

State mapping:

```
clearData: () => dispatch(actions.clearData()),
validateInvoices: () => dispatch(actions.validateInvoices())
```

The errors:
[image: not a function]
[image: internal method not a function]

EDIT: the problem with componentDidUpdate is that when calling loadInvoicesFromFile, loadInvoicesFromFile is anonymous (no other function is anonymous), the component can't load the file so it shows nothing. Any suggestions? It's declared exactly like other functions which ARE NOT anonymous.

The code for the method:

```
loadInvoicesFromFile = (invoicesCollection, debtors) => {
        const invoicesData = [];
        if(invoicesCollection) {
            invoicesCollection.map((x, i) => {
                // just some logic
                }
            });

            this.props.loadInvoices(invoicesData);
        } else{
            this.props.clearData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` has two params and these are `nextProps, prevState`, there is no `oldProps`, the major difference between `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentWillReceiveProps` is that you don't have access to `this.props` in `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Comment: @NicolaeMaties I understood that, but as far as I know, there is no other choice. What I need doesn't render if I used componentDidUpdate (according to React documentation, if I want to achieve a side effect, I can simply use the didUpdate method) so my only choice is this static method. Are there no workarounds for accessing the props of the component?

Comment: This might answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723019/compare-with-previous-props-in-getderivedstatefromprops